# Issues with Jboss server start up

Tags: jboss5.x

i am unable to start the Jboss server.

below one is the error : org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException
server is : JBoss_5_1_0_GA

complete log file:

```
536)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtensio
n.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.g
etLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:207)
        ... 126 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish t
he connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.j
ava:422)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
        ... 131 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
        ... 136 more
19:11:48,777 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
19:11:48,777 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/yadweb] startup failed due to pre
vious errors
19:11:48,782 INFO  [[/yadweb]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:11:48,814 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jb
oss.web.deployment:war=/yadweb state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/ProgramFiles/JBoss5YCC
/server/yad/deploy/yadweb.war/ deployment failed
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
Internal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeploy
ment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatch
er.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.
java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java
:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installActio
n(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installActio
n(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.sim
pleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.ins
tall(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install
(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(Serv
iceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:68
8)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java
:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.jav
a:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.jav
a:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.i
nternalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(
AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(Deployer
Wrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(Deployer
sImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(Deployers
Impl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(Deployers
Impl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeploye
rImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter
.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction
.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileActi
on.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(
ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
19:11:48,825 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs
file:/D:/ProgramFiles/JBoss5YCC/server/Lad/deploy/Ladweb.war/ state=PreReal mode
=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/ProgramFiles/JBoss5YCC
/server/Lad/deploy/yadweb.war/ deployment failed
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
Internal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeploy
ment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatch
er.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.
java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java
:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installActio
n(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installActio
n(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.sim
pleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.ins
tall(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install
(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(Serv
iceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:68
8)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java
:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.jav
a:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.jav
a:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.i
nternalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(
AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(Deployer
Wrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(Deployer
sImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(Deployers
Impl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(Deployers
Impl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeploye
rImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter
.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction
.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileActi
on.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(
ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
19:11:48,864 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of
incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/D:/ProgramFiles/JBoss5YCC/server/Lad/deploy/yadweb.war/"
is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentEx
ception: URL file:/D:/ProgramFiles/JBoss5YCC/server/Lad/deploy/yadweb.war/ deplo
yment failed

19:11:48,873 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-968
0
19:11:48,885 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=
JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 1m:1s:782ms
```

Please give me some suggestion as i am new to Jboss.

Comment: Seems like you have a connection problem to your database. Check you firewall settings and verify that you can reach your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

This tells you the cause - you were unable to connect to your Oracle database. There might be a network issue or the oracle listener might not be up, for example. Or the data source is just configured wrong.